# Why I can use react-data-picker in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, datepicker, webpack-dev-server

I try to add DataPicker to my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';

class TestPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    date: new Date()
  };    
  this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
}

handleOnChange(date) {
  this.setState(date);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I install react-data-picker like this:

```
npm i react-date-picker@6.7.0
```

But after this I have errors in console.

**Nodemon**:

> module.js:549
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'react-calendar/dist/shared/locales'

**Webpack-dev-server**:

> ERROR in ./~/react-date-picker/dist/shared/locales.js Module not
>   found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'react-calendar/dist/shared/locales' in
>   /home/jack/Документы/myapp/frontend/node_modules/react-date-picker/dist/shared
>   @ ./~/react-date-picker/dist/shared/locales.js 7:15-60

How can I fix it? Or maybe I should use other datapickers for my app?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker/issues/97

Comment: @OliverRadini yes, it's help for me! But now I have new issue: calendar opening under other elements on page. How to change z-index of react-data-picker? May be you know

Comment: I believe this may help: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1252

Comment: @OliverRadini I add code from github to file _datapicker.scss, import to file style.scss (@import 'datapicker';) and build it (use 'npm run build'). After this I get style.css and put it to my project (replace old style.css). But nothing has changed. What's wrong?